# MVC 5 ViewComponent namespace reference missing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I am using mvc 5 and creating ViewComponent. Facing namespace missing reference error.

> The type or namespace name 'ViewComponent' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

here is code sample

```
public class SumViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    public IViewComponentResult Invoke(int a, int b)
    {
        return this.Content($"<span class=\"result\">{a + b}</span>");
    }
}
```

How can i resolve namespace issue, is it supported in mvc 5 application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MVC 5 does not have ViewComponents, they were introduced with MVC 6.  See [this article](https://dotnet.today/en/aspnet5-mvc6/views/view-components.html)